# Samba does not start correctly

Tags: windows-7, samba, openwrt

I have an older router with OpenWRT operating system. I have a connection configured via OpenVPN and file sharing via Samba. However, after restarting the router, Samba won't start properly because I can't get to the network folder. However, when I connect to the router via Telnet, kill the Samba process and restart it, everything is fine. What could be the problem?

Samba starts automatically as `smbd -D`, but I start it manually along with its configuration file.

I am using Windows 7 operating system.

I will be very grateful for any help, I can't figure it out myself...

Comment: Then update `OpenWRT` if you can. Don't mindlessly kill a process if it does not function. Use the various tools to interrogate it.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?